# Compile and add dictionary key values within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Below I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict = [{'name': 'Sector',
  'entity': 'ORG(100.0), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
  'definition': 'Sector: a plane figure bounded by two radii and the included arc of a circle',
  'sentiment': '',
  'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'Community Name',
  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74), GPE(22.88), ORG(20.57), LOC(9.95), FAC(3.6), NORP(2.02), CARDINAL(0.45), LAW(0.39), DATE(0.39), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district'], Name:['advert', 'appoint', 'bring_up', 'call', 'cite', 'constitute', 'describe', 'diagnose', 'discover', 'distinguish', 'epithet', 'figure', 'gens', 'identify', 'key', 'key_out', 'list', 'make', 'mention', 'name', 'nominate', 'public_figure', 'refer'], ",
  'definition': 'Community: a group of people living in a particular local area, Name: a language unit by which a person or thing is known',
  'sentiment': '',
  'name': 'don'}]
```

How do I add a new key that groups entity, synonyms, definition, and sentiment as values?

desired output (nlp is the new added key):

```
dict = [{'name': 'Sector',

  'nlp': {

  'entity': 'ORG(100.0), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
  'definition': 'Sector: a plane figure bounded by two radii and the included arc of a circle',
  'sentiment': ''},
  'name': 'john'},

  {'name': 'Community Name',

  'nlp':{

  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74), GPE(22.88), ORG(20.57), LOC(9.95), FAC(3.6), NORP(2.02), CARDINAL(0.45), LAW(0.39), DATE(0.39), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district'], Name:['advert', 'appoint', 'bring_up', 'call', 'cite', 'constitute', 'describe', 'diagnose', 'discover', 'distinguish', 'epithet', 'figure', 'gens', 'identify', 'key', 'key_out', 'list', 'make', 'mention', 'name', 'nominate', 'public_figure', 'refer'], ",
  'definition': 'Community: a group of people living in a particular local area, Name: a language unit by which a person or thing is known',
  'sentiment': ''},
  'name': 'don'}]
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: your dictionary has duplicate keys `'name': 'Community Name'` and `'name': 'don'`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of `dict`. And looks like you need to add `entity, synonyms, definition, and sentiment`  under `nlp` key

Using a list comprehension with `dict.pop`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'name': 'Sector',
  'entity': 'ORG(100.0), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
  'definition': 'Sector: a plane figure bounded by two radii and the included arc of a circle',
  'sentiment': '',
  'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'Community Name',
  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74), GPE(22.88), ORG(20.57), LOC(9.95), FAC(3.6), NORP(2.02), CARDINAL(0.45), LAW(0.39), DATE(0.39), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district'], Name:['advert', 'appoint', 'bring_up', 'call', 'cite', 'constitute', 'describe', 'diagnose', 'discover', 'distinguish', 'epithet', 'figure', 'gens', 'identify', 'key', 'key_out', 'list', 'make', 'mention', 'name', 'nominate', 'public_figure', 'refer'], ",
  'definition': 'Community: a group of people living in a particular local area, Name: a language unit by which a person or thing is known',
  'sentiment': '',
  'name': 'don'}]

result = [{'name': i.pop('name'), 'nlp': i}  for i in data]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'john',
  'nlp': {'definition': 'Sector: a plane figure bounded by two radii and the '
                        'included arc of a circle',
          'entity': 'ORG(100.0), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, '
                    'nan, nan, nan, nan',
          'sentiment': '',
          'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , "}},
 {'name': 'don',
  'nlp': {'definition': 'Community: a group of people living in a particular '
                        'local area, Name: a language unit by which a person '
                        'or thing is known',
          'entity': 'PERSON(39.74), GPE(22.88), ORG(20.57), LOC(9.95), '
                    'FAC(3.6), NORP(2.02), CARDINAL(0.45), LAW(0.39), '
                    'DATE(0.39), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan',
          'sentiment': '',
          'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', "
                      "'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', "
                      "'residential_district'], Name:['advert', 'appoint', "
                      "'bring_up', 'call', 'cite', 'constitute', 'describe', "
                      "'diagnose', 'discover', 'distinguish', 'epithet', "
                      "'figure', 'gens', 'identify', 'key', 'key_out', 'list', "
                      "'make', 'mention', 'name', 'nominate', 'public_figure', "
                      "'refer'], "}}]
```